# List of Dictionaries with Collection Initializer

Tags: c#

what the heck am I doing wrong?

```
var rows = new List<Dictionary<int, int>> { new Dictionary<int, int> {1, 2} };
```

Intellisense is telling me an error "Method Add has 2 parameters but is invoked with one"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the initialization of `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` you have to specify the keys and values, for sample:

```
var rows = new List<Dictionary<int, int>> 
           { 
              new Dictionary<int, int> 
              {
                 {1 /*key*/, 2 /*value*/},
                 {2 /*key*/, 2 /*value*/},
                 {3 /*key*/, 3 /*value*/},
              }
            };
```

Comment: Or `{ { 1, 2 } }` if the aim was to have a single entry.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan: Yes, it works - because it's just a single entry. We don't know whether the OP intended one key/value pair or two...

Comment: @JonSkeet As I know, with this syntax, the compiler must call the List<T> Add method with 2 arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var rows = new List<Dictionary<int, int>> { new Dictionary<int, int>() { { 1, 2 } } };
```